# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found When using header

Tags: android-ndk

I have the following:

jniinterface.h

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C" {
  JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_gleason_finance_JniLib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jdouble SO, jdouble U, jdouble D, jdouble R);
};
```

jniinterface.cpp

```
#include "jniinterface.h"
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_gleason_finance_JniLib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jdouble SO, jdouble U, jdouble D, jdouble R, jint N, jdouble K)
{
  return 0.0;
}
```

But this returns the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3638): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.me.finance.JniLib.init:(DDDDID)D
```

It works fine if I change jniinterface.cpp to:

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_gleason_finance_JniLib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jdouble SO, jdouble U, jdouble D, jdouble R, jint N, jdouble K)
{
  return 0.0;
}
```

It works, I am kind of new to C++ so am I doing something wrong? Should I just remove the header? Why doesn't it work with the header?

Not sure why this will help since it is clearly a C++ issue (because of the C fix) but here:

```
public class JniLib {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("fin");
  }
  public static native double init(double SO, double U, double R, double D, int N, double k);
}
```

Comment: Show your Java file, please, where this method is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jniinterface.h, the return type of the function is void. It needs to be jdouble! You can leave jniinterface.cpp as it was in the first snippet.

**Edit**: You are also missing two parameters in the header file. (named N and K)

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C" {
  JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_gleason_finance_JniLib_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jdouble SO, jdouble U, jdouble D, jdouble R, jint N, jdouble K);
};
```

Whenever you see an error like this, the first thing you should do is carefully go over the method signatures - name, package, parameter and return type. Any small mistake leads to this general error!

Comment: @Jackie Looked again and your definition in the header file is also missing parameters. Updated my answer

Comment: Good call that looks like it worked... too much undo redo I guess.